# Как найти словосочетание на сайте

Tags: поиск, браузер

Есть сайт [НГУ](https://nsu.ru), на нем есть раздел `Списки абитуриентов`-https://education.nsu.ru/abitura/. Нужно ввести данные (факультет, платно или бюджет и так далее). Хочу найти человека, то есть знаю его `ФИО`. Можно ли как-то найти, обойдя нудный поиск по всем спискам, в каком из всех списков есть он, или хотя бы есть ли он хотя бы среди этих списков

Comment: А обычный поиск ctrl+f не помогает?

Comment: Нет, если перейти на сайт со Списками абитуриентов, и попробовать ввести, то нет.

Comment: Странно, я выбрал тип подавшие заявления и бюджет и через поиск нашел человека

Comment: По другому даже не знаю как.

Comment: Ну вот если без выбора, то есть не заполнять никаких данных.

Comment: а как без выбора? сразу все списки не хранятся на сайте. После выбора только всех параметров отправляется запрос(POST) и возвращает список.
Только выбрав нужный список, когда отображается таблица можно найти как сказали выше через ctrl + f